# Does asymptotically unbiased mean convergence in probability?

Tags: asymptotics, consistency

I'm arguing with a friend and he doesn't have a solid argument for his statement.
I claim that if a random variable is asymptotically unbiased then it is consistent, and that implies convergence in probability:

Example: Suppose i have a estimator $\hat{\theta}$ for a parameter $\theta$.
Suppose that $E(\hat{\theta}) = \frac{n}{n+1} \theta$

Then because $\lim_{n\to \infty} E(\hat{\theta}) = \theta$ i can claim that the estimator $\hat{\theta}$ converges in probability to $\theta$.

Is that right? I can show this reasoning to my friend?

---

Thank's guys! Now i have a better idea:

Suppose i can state what i previously wrote and i can state that the variance of the estimator is finite. Is that sufficient to state that there is convergence in probability?

I'm with a statemente that is the variance converges nummerically to cero, then the convergence is in cuadratic mean, but that is a stronger statement.

Comment: The information about the expectation is so incredibly weak that it's implausible it would imply convergence of the underlying distribution.  Imagine a series of estimators with the given expectations and the same shapes, but scaled so that their variances grow without limit: they won't converge to any distribution at all, in any sense of convergence!

Comment: hmm that's right, but if i can show that the variance doesn't grow can i claim what i wrote? @whuber ?

Comment: Even if the variance doesn't grow, the approach is hopeless: the mean and variance determine little about the distribution unless you make strong additional assumptions.  In the counterexample posted by @StasK the variance stays constant, for instance: you should study that more closely. If the variance shrinks to zero, a lot can be said by virtue of Chebyshev's Inequality.

Comment: Ahh ok ok i get it..

Comment: Final question: Is there any other way to check when does a random variable converges in probability to a constant? Besides the traditional definition:
Let {$X_{n}$} be a sequence of random variables. $X_{n}$ converges in probability to a constant c if:
$\lim_{n\to \infty} Prob( |X_{n} - c| > \epsilon) = 0, \forall \epsilon > 0 $
@whuber

Answer (score 10):

Let $Y_i \sim \mbox{i.i.d. } N(\mu,1)$. Then $\hat\theta_n=Y_n$ is an unbiased (and hence asymptotically unbiased) estimator of $\mu$. However, it does not converge in probability, and thus is not consistent.

1. Unbiasedness: the expected value should be the population mean -- check: $E[\hat\theta_n]\equiv E[Y_n]=\mu$.
2. Convergence in probability: probabilities of large deviations should be going to zero -- fail: ${\rm Prob}[ |\hat\theta_n-\theta| > a] \equiv {\rm Prob}[ |Y_n-\theta| > a]  = 2 \Phi( -a )$ does not go down with $n$ and does not converge to zero.

Comment: I don't know what to say here, honestly. This is applying the definition.